# How to get new hard drives into a QNAP NAS and transfer the old data from static volume

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, raid, nas, qnap

I want to make sure this plan works.

**Existing setup:** 2-bay QNAS NAS drive containing two 1TB drives. No RAID. One drive is a "Static Volume" and one is a "Legacy Volume" (from an earlier NAS).

**Want to go to:** 2 larger drives (4 or 8TB) in RAID 1.

**Plan:**

1. Back up system settings to laptop.
2. Remove existing drives from NAS.
3. Remove old drives; insert new drives.
4. Format new drives as a RAID 1 storage pool.
5. Attach old drives one by one to USB port on NAS device, using an ordinary HD enclosure.
6. Copy the contents of the old drive to the new drive (probably ssh and rsync, but whatever).
7. Erase old drives and donate to charity.

Comment: If your NAS software is capable of backing up your data or even hot swap the drives, I would do that instead of the hustle connecting the drives via usb and copying everything over.

Comment: My only suggestion is check to see if you can actually mount the two existing drives in an external enclosure. Past that, the plan sounds fine.

Comment: Turns out, @Giacomo1968 had a useful warning. The NAS uses a software raid configuration and one of the two drives will _not_ mount when dropped into an enclosure. I'll have to do some software magic to get it to mount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some ways this turned out to be more complicated than I thought, and then, easier.

As [@Giacomo1968 was warning me](https://superuser.com/a/1769833/167207), connecting the earlier QNAP "static volume" (single disk) through a QNAP device USB port was *not* smooth sailing. I am not the first person to [discover](https://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?t=143917) [this](https://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?t=127980). For reasons that escape me, QNAP won't recognize its own software RAID pattern here. An older "legacy volume" (previous format) mounted. The static volume did not.

Nor did it mount attached to a MacBook Pro. The solution was hinted from [here](https://alex3305.github.io/home-assistant-docs/homelab/qnap-linux-mount/). I created an Ubuntu VM with Parallels (my guess is VirtualBox would also work), and attached the USB enclosure to the VM.

The software steps indicated at that link turned out to be unnecessary. The VM mounted the static volume right away, no need to run `lvscan`. (I did install it, in case I needed it.)

The only downside of this solution is of course the file copy from the older volumes onto the enlarged NAS RAID is much slower than a direct connect through the USB port.

Answer (score 2):

### Check if the NAS drives can even be mounted in an external enclosure.

> “I want to make sure this plan works.”

Okay, if that is the case then you need to address this key step before you do anything:

> “Attach old drives one by one to USB port on NAS device, using an ordinary HD enclosure.”

This might seem obvious, but you really should check to see if you can actually mount the two existing drives in an external enclosure. Not all drives are formatted equally in NAS setups and while some *might* allow an  individual volume to be mounted in a stand-alone external enclosure, some NAS setups format the drive in some “weird” way that doesn’t make the process easy.

I recommend before you do anything, power down the NAS, take out each drive and see if you can actually mount them at all.

If you can’t do that, the whole plan won’t work.

But past that one major stumbling block, the plan sounds fine.